# Issue with Array of fixed count

Tags: solidity, mapping, truffle-contract

What is the difference between using mapping and without mapping?

can I declare the tickets variable with mapping? `Ticket[TOTAL_TICKETS] public tickets;`

Here is the solidity smartcontract

```js
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

uint256 constant TOTAL_TICKETS = 10;

contract Tickets {
  address public owner = msg.sender;

  struct Ticket {
    uint256 price;
    address owner;
  }
  //mapping(uint256 => Ticket) public tickets;
  Ticket[TOTAL_TICKETS] public tickets;

  constructor() {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < TOTAL_TICKETS; i++) {
      tickets[i].price = 1e17; // 0.1 ETH
      tickets[i].owner = address(0x0);
    }
  }

  function buyTicket(uint256 _index) external payable {
    require(_index < TOTAL_TICKETS && _index >= 0);
    require(tickets[_index].owner == address(0x0));
    require(msg.value >= tickets[_index].price);
    tickets[_index].owner = msg.sender;
  }
}
```

I get an error in truffle console when fetching tickets

```js
truffle(development)> Tickets.deployed().then(function(instance) { app=instance})
undefined
truffle(development)> app.tickets()
Uncaught Error: Invalid number of parameters for "tickets". Got 0 expected 1!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tickets` state variable is an array, so you need to send the index of the ticket that you want. Something like:

```js
app.tickets(0)
```

But anyway, a `mapping` may be more convenient for you in this case.

I suggest you to create an `id` member for the `Ticket` struct. Each ticket should have its own id to be able to identify it correctly, modify it, etc.

The approach I suggest would look like this:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

type TicketId is uint256;

contract Tickets {

  event TicketSold(TicketId id, address ticketOwner);

  address public owner = msg.sender;

  struct Ticket {
    TicketId id;
    uint256 price;
    address owner;
  }
  mapping(TicketId => Ticket) public tickets;

  modifier onlyOwner {
      require(owner == msg.sender);
      _;
  }

  // Maybe you want to be able to add tickets dynamically
  function addTicket(TicketId id, uint256 price) public onlyOwner {
      tickets[id] = Ticket(id, price, address(0x0));
  }

  // Maybe you want to be able to remove tickets?
  function removeTicket(TicketId id) public onlyOwner {
      delete tickets[id];
  }

  function buyTicket(TicketId id) external payable {
    require(tickets[id].owner == address(0x0), "Ticket already bought.");
    require(msg.value >= tickets[id].price, "Not enough balance to buy the ticket");
    tickets[id].owner = msg.sender;
    emit TicketSold(id, msg.sender);
  }
}
```

Maybe there's no need for a `TOTAL_TICKETS` anymore. But you could change the logic to have a state variable to count the total tickets and make sure not to add more than that.

Using a `mapping` is more efficient for general lookups (compared to looping through an array, although accessing an array element by an index is efficient as with the mapping).

A `mapping` is more efficient to remove elements from it. Deleting an element by index on an array is efficient, but usually, you want to resize the array so you don't have empty space in the array, and the complexity of that is linear, compared to constant when deleting an element from a mapping.

I used custom types in my implementation to make it clear that the key of the mapping is the id of the ticket, to make it more readable and type-safe.

Comment: Why the error with Array?Could that be resolved

Comment: You didn't send the index of the array element while calling `app.tickets` function. You called `app.tickets()` you should have called `app.tickets(0)` or `app.tickets(1)`, etc.

Comment: okay. I understood .